# @style/Widget.Material3.Button causing render problem

Tags: android, android-studio, material-ui, material-components-android

When I'm applying style to my button `@style/Widget.Material3.Button` then it is making the whole layout design disappear and the layout is not visible anymore.

Here is my XML Code.

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:text="Text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textField" />
```

Is there any solution to solve this render problem?

Answer (score 0):

For Material style you need to use Material components.
`com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`

Comment: I've used this, but again I'm facing the rendering problem.

Comment: @gauravkumar What rendering problem?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Motion easing theme attribute must be an @interpolator resource for ?attr/motionEasing*Interpolator attributes or a string for ?attr/motionEasing* attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to themes and change the parent element of your style to:

Comment: Yeah, I've used 'Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar' but still some of my layouts have render problems.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got rendering problem too after updating from Android Studio Bumblebee into Android Studio Dolphin version 2021.3.1 patch 1 in the same project (nothing changed, no code changed and suddenly it just error rendering).

I used this style

`style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.Icon"`

try the solution listed in this

[Failed to find '@attr/shapeAppearanceSmallComponent' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278863/failed-to-find-attr-shapeappearancesmallcomponent-in-current-theme)

in my case, I added this line in my theme files, because it caused rendering problem saying that it failed to find attr/textAppearanceLabelLarge in my current theme.

```
 <item name="textAppearanceLabelLarge">@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge</item>
```

So whatever is missing, just fill it in in your theme files.